# Why won’t this section stay contained when I change my browser screen size? HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Why won’t this section stay contained when I change my browser screen size? I used HTML and CSS. It looks fine when I made my screen full size but then if I make my browser smaller it doesn’t show the full content. (it only shows half of the image but shows the full text) [screenshot of how it looks on smaller browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9qiK.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9qiK.jpg)

`````
.whoweare{
    padding:80px 0px 50px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.whoweare .content {
    -webkit-display: flex;
    display: flex;
}

.whoweare .content .box{
    padding:5px;
    flex:0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.whoweare .content .item-img {
    width: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    padding: 30px;
    
}

.whoweare  .content .item-text h2{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin:20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px;
}

.whoweare .content .item-text p{
  font-size: 20px;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin:20px;
    padding:0px 0px 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.whoweare  .content .class-items .item{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
}
.whoweare  .content .class-items .item .item-text{
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}



` <section class="whoweare" id="whoweare">
     <dic class="container">
    <div class="content">
<div class="box text wow slideInRight">
   <div class="class-items">
    <div class="item wow bounceInUp">
     <div class="item-img">
          <img src="images/ACD68359-D3EB-4302-99C0-E59A663380AB.jpeg" alt="classes" width="601"
          height="751" />
     </div>
     <div class="item-text">
        <h2>Who we are</h2>
        <p>Our gym provides a unique experience </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>````
`````

Comment: What do you want it to look like when the viewport, especially the aspect ratio changes? Which part of the image is to show? It would help us to give a fully tested answer if you create a runnable snippet, including the actual image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Change the height width of img tags.

Use % parameters

for example

height=50%

width=60%.

I think  you need also change the height width of other container tags
If design is not look like good

Answer (score 0):

You should add to all importan containers`

```
    .container
    {
    width:100%:
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    }
//Also can try
.container
{
width: auto;
padding: 0;

}
```

that should work...

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

`img` has specific width and height, hence it overflows even though its container (in your case `.item-img` has `width:50%;`).

### Answer

Give the `img` of `width: 100%;` and `object-fit: contain` **or** `object-fit: cover` if you want it **cropped**.

Comment: I tried that but then it crops the text

Comment: Yes, it would because .item-img has width:50%; and .item-text do not has a width spcified. Try removing the percentage width and use flex-basis. The cropping and overflowing shouldn't be because of the img, but of .item-img container. There are only two contextual elements inside your main container (the img and the text), and you use flexbox. It should be pretty easy to set things up.